# Availability of User Management FullStory APIs and Retrieval of uid for FullStory URI

Tags: go, terraform, uid, terraform-provider

I am currently working to make providers using Terraform in Go language.

Are there FullStory APIs that would allow me to create, read, update and delete users.

With reference to this https://developer.fullstory.com/delete-user, the UID (unique id) is the application-specific ID that we've given to the user. We will have to pass that ID through the FS.identify Browser API function. How can I get a specific UID to add it in the URI to check the APIs functionality in Postman?

Comment: your question is too broad to be answered correctly. Try to expand a little on what you are trying to accomplish. Share a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve and explain what you have tried and the errors you encounter. For more information, please check [the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find more information about how to write a good question.

Comment: I have edited it, please check now.